# Скачать картинку или показать с сайта

Tags: c#

Что, можно так сказать, будет грузиться быстрее.
Скачивать картинку с сайта при запуске программы и вывести.
Или поставить элемент браузера и выводить через него сайт с картинкой.

Comment: лучше для чего?

Comment: Думаю для здравого смысла

Comment: А какая разница? Картинка лежит на сайте, её в любом случае надо скачать. Грузить целый браузер для одной картинки ИМХО чересчур.

Comment: Ну, а если картинка на моём сайте и запрос будет только 1?

Comment: Как минимум будет два запроса - за страницей, а потом за картинкой. И как уже писали выше, нецелесообразно использовать браузер для одной только картинки.

Comment: Спасибо. Значит буду качать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идет о здравом смысле, то сначала стоит понять, что же все-таки необходимо сделать. Ибо два описанных для сравнения случая приводят к абсолютно разным результатам.

А если по поставленному вопросу, то все будет зависеть от реализации. Концептуально первый вариант будет работать быстрее, хотя бы потому что запрос будет выполняться не за всей страницей (и еще неизвестно сколько запросов будет выполнено с этой страницы), а только за одним изображением.